# Proof that if T is Transitive Tournament T Has Unique Hamiltonian Path

Tags: graph-theory

A few of us have been looking to prove this but we've been struggling. We've found some proofs online that prove in the wrong direction (if T has unique path then T is transitive).

If you could point us in the right direction or just give us something to work with that would be great just we're completely stumped.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: "$T$ has a unique Hamiltonian path" can be broken down into two simpler statements: "$T$ has a Hamiltonian path" and "$T$ has no more than one Hamiltonian path." Which one(s) are you struggling with?

Comment: T has no more than one Hamiltonian path (I really should have included this, we got a bit stuck on this one).

Comment: Can you please tell me where you found the other direction of the proof? (If there is only 1 hamiltonian path then it is transitive) I didn't find that yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the comments, you're satisfied that $T$ has a Hamiltonian path; you just don't know that it's unique.

Suppose $T$ has multiple distinct Hamiltonian paths; label the vertices so there are two paths $H_1=p_1\dots p_n$, $H_2=p_{\pi(1)}\dots p_{\pi(n)}$ where $\pi$ is a non-identity permutation.

Since $T$ is transitive, there is an arc from $p_i$ to $p_j$ whenever $j > i$. Since  $\pi$ is a non-identity permutation, there must be some $i, j$ such that $j > i$ but $\pi(i) > \pi(j)$. Can you obtain a contradiction?